# How can I make this grid layout allow for more space on a longer name item?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Is there a way using `display: grid` that I can allow the item whose name is longer to have a larger section in the grid than the short items?

I would like the below navigation to all be on the same line and not have the longer name wrap to a second line. If anyone has a creative solution I am open to using javascript or jquery to achieve this if necessary.

```css
.nav {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="">Item with a long name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto)` instead of `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr))`

```css
.nav {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover {
  //font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow:1px 0px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="">Item with a long name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works. Any way this could be tweaked so that the hover effect doesn't move the other elements in the navigation?

Comment: What's your hover effect ?

Comment: The hover effect that is in the code above makes the hovered item turn bold, when this happens the size of the element increases pushing the other nav items over in the process. It is most noticeable when hovering the element with the longer name.

Comment: You can use `text-shadow:1px 0px 0px black` instead of `font-weight: 900`. With this property, you will not change the size of the container. I edited the answer